# How to wrap all the body contents in a div with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-plugins

In a JQuery plugin I'm writing I want to hide all the contents of the `<body>` tag by wrapping them in a div and calling `.hide()`. What is the best way to wrap existing DOM elements into a single parent element?

For example:

I want to turn this

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>This is a sample document to be manipulated by a JQuery plugin!</p>
</body>
```

into this

```
<body>
    <div id="originalBodyContents">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <p>This is a sample document to be manipulated by a JQuery plugin!</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do it...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').wrapInner('<div class="new" />');
    $('.new').hide();
});
```

[Here's a little fiddle to show something similar in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/z7YdT/1/)

Comment: It always ends up being easier than I thought :). Thanks!

Comment: Link to the docs explaining what `wrapInner` does: http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/ Also, fixed a typo. :-)

Comment: @AlexFord for completeness, there's also `.wrapAll()`

Comment: Thanks guys. In case anyone is wondering how I used this, my plugin maintains a var reference to the original elements like this: `var $bodyContents = $('body').wrapInner('<div>').children('div').hide();` then later I am able to easily do `$bodyContents.show()` :)

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason why you don't want to do the following?

```
$('body').hide();​​​​
```

Comment: Yes because I want to hide the original body contents and add a new div, specific to the plugin, to the body that will not be hidden. Then when the plugin exits it will remove its div and reshow the original body contents.

Comment: @AlexFord well you could do this without doing that wrapper, by having a CSS rule to hide everything and another rule to expose just the new element.

Comment: @Pointy true, but I think I like having control over the original body elements in a simple container.

Comment: @AlexFord yes good point, plus `*` rules are kind-of expensive.